# Отравка фото на API OK

Tags: php, api

Делаю постер товаров в Одноклассники. Все права получены, использую вечный токен доступа. API работает проверял на множестве методов. Но возникла проблема с загрузкой фотографии к самому товару. 
Вот мой код:

```html
<?php
    require("./ok_lib.php");
    $LOT=380143;

    function load_photo($file) {
    global $LOT;
    $upload_url = OdnoklassnikiSDK::makeRequest("photosV2.getUploadUrl");

    $id=$upload_url['photo_ids'][0];
    $upload_url=$upload_url['upload_url'];

    //Получение фото из cloud.bugrealt.by
    $photo=str_replace('"','', shell_exec("curl  -v  -H 'Authorization: Token XXXXXXXXXXX' -H 'Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8; indent=4' '194.158.219.97:8000/api2/repos/972a9d27-e2a8-411a-9bea-86889c770a6f/file/?p=/".$LOT."/".$file."'"));
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/poster/temp/temp.jpg';
    file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($photo));

    //Загружаем файл на сервер OK
    $ch = curl_init();
    $parameters = [
        'pic1' => new \CURLFile($path)
    ];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    preg_match_all('/.+token":"(.*)"/Uis', $response, $mach);
    $token=$mach[1][0];
    echo $token;
    echo '<hr>';
    return($token);
    }



    $id1=load_photo('01.JPG');
    $id2=load_photo('02.JPG');
    $id3=load_photo('03.JPG');
    $id4=load_photo('04.JPG');
    $id5=load_photo('05.JPG');
    $id6=load_photo('06.JPG');
    $id7=load_photo('07.JPG');
    $id8=load_photo('08.JPG');
    $id9=load_photo('09.JPG');



    $content='{"media":[
                        {"type":"text","text":"Название товара"},
                        {"type":"text","text":"Описание товара"},
                        {
                            "type": "photo",
                            "list": [
                                {"id": "'.$id1.'"}, 
                             {"id": "'.$id2.'"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {"type":"product","price":1000,"lifetime": 30}
              ]}';

    echo $content.'<hr>';


    $response=OdnoklassnikiSDK::makeRequest("market.add", array("gid" => "54352824500462",
                                                                            "type" => "GROUP_PRODUCT",
                                                                            "attachment" => $content,
                                                                            ));

    var_dump($response);



    ?>
```

```
Вот что пишет:
```

```html
{ ["error_code"]=> int(300) ["error_msg"]=> string(41) "NOT_FOUND : not.found.photouploadinglocal" ["error_data"]=> NULL }
```

Пишет что фотография не загружена на сервер, хотя мне и пришел ответ с токеном фотографии. Помогоите!

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю что тема старая, но такие как я, которые гуглят эту проблему не смогут найти ни одного решения на просторах сети интернет!

Решение очень простое.

Если вы грузите фотографии в ОК не для личных целей ( без мета информации)
Не нужно вызывать метод валидации этих фотографий!
То есть, получили uploadURL, выполнили загрузку, получили данные о фотке (айтишник и токен доступа) на этом все, этого достаточно! Не вызывайте метод photosV2.commit

Нужно просто загрузить токен и получить токен, валидацию выполнять не нужно!!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]